# Change NSAttributedString text color without having to set title again

Tags: ios, swift

Is it possible to change a `NSAttributedString` color without having to set the `title` again?

I've tried:

```
for case let i as UIButton in myView.subviews {
    if i.backgroundColor != UIColor.greenColor() && i.backgroundColor != UIColor.grayColor() {
          i.titleLabel?.textColor = color
       // i.setTitleColor(color, forState: .Normal)
       // i.setTitleColor(color, forState: .Selected)
       // i.tintColor = color
    }                             
}
```

`i.titleLabel.textcolor` changes the color of the `.Normal` state but not the `.Selected` state

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do just set the color without setting the title but you can do it using `attributedTitleForState(.Selected)` and accessing its string property. You can also create your own setAttributedTitleColor method extending UIButton as follow:

```
extension UIButton {
    func setAttributedTitleColor(color: UIColor, forState: UIControlState) {
        guard let title = attributedTitleForState(forState)?.string else { return }
        setAttributedTitle(NSAttributedString(string: title, attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName : color]), forState: forState)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
setAttributedTitleColor(color, forState:.Selected)
```

instead.

Comment: i tried setting i.setAttributedTitleColor(color, forState:.Selected) and im getting an error: UIButton has no member  setAttributedTitleColor